# How do I deny access to part of a url parameter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, redirect

For example.  Say I have this url.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/posts.php?id=54
```

How do I make sure that I don't access that page as the following?

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/posts.php
```

Also, how do I block/redirect someone if they have entered a id that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

Use logic inside the PHP.

If the `id` isn't provided, then issue a `404` status and an error message instead of the regular page.

If you get no results back from the database query I assume you are making, then do the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if `$_GET['id']` is empty. If it is, then display a message like "You have no rights to access the page" or simply send a 404 HTTP header.
Then query your database to find if the provided Id exists. Be careful! Use PDO or something similar to be safe from SQL injections since the Id is input by a user.
If the Id doesn't exist in database, do a `header("location: ...");` to redirect the user to a certain page or, again, send a 404 HTTP header.
Note: you should do this before any `echo` call or use output buffering (`ob_*` functions).

Comment: Yep it does the trick against an empty id.  But I am also looking to get 404 error if another id that doesn't exist is entered in the url. How would that be done?

Comment: To do this, query your database selecting a row with the provided Id. If there is one, then the Id exists, if the row is not found, then the Id is non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

If ID is not exist:

```
header('HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found');
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
include_once '404.php';
```

404.php - custom 404 status page.

Answer (score 0):

[Manual php.net url_parser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Use some like this:

`
$url = 'http://username:password@fernandohcorrea.com.br/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);